# Bose-Einstein-statistics out of fermionic many body system

Tags: quantum-statistics

ok, let me try this again.

How do I get to atoms obeying Bose Einstein statistics from considering the fermionic many body problem of a bunch of electrons, protons and neutrons forming these (bosonic) atoms.

[ORIGINAL QUESTION]
this keeps bugging me: Whenever there is a system of bosons (lets not consider photons/phonons) then we use BE statistics to describe it. But shouldn't we also be able to describe it (more accurately) by FD statistics with regard to its constituent electrons, protons and neutrons?
How is this consistent with the symmetry requirements on the wave function and phenomenas as Bose Einstein condensation?

Comment: Surely this is just a matter of whether the energy available is sufficient to excite fermionic degrees of freedom. In liquid helium or a superconductor there is not enough energy so the fermionic degrees of freedom are invisible and the system behaves like bosons. Add more energy, e.g. heat your superconductor, and it it will go back to obeying fermionic statistics.

Comment: I don't get it. What happens in between

1. behaving like bosons and
2. going back to obeying fermionic statistics

Comment: To be honest I've never thought about it, though obviously the distribution will change smoothly from BE to FD. In many cases, e.g. heating Helium enough to ionise it, there will be so much energy in the system that it ends up obeying Boltzmann statistics anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system constitutes a complex mix of  elementary fermions with extremely strong interactions. If you take the full many body Hamiltonian and renormalize out the large energies i.e. do a long wavelength expansion, it should yield an effective Hamiltonian consisting of quasiparticles that are the individual "atoms", but they obey Bosonic statistics. I have no idea is this can be done rigorously, though. Probably not. Maybe using DFT or something...